# Determine if ng-content selector matched anything

Tags: angular, angular14, angular-content-projection

When using content projection with a selector, like so:

```html
<ng-content select="[appChecklistTitle]">
```

How can I tell whether or not anything was matched? Basically I want an, "If content provided put it here, otherwise use some default content".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest using the [ng-template](https://angular.io/api/core/ng-template) in such cases, by passing it from the parent, and handling it in the child as a [ContentChild](https://angular.io/api/core/ContentChild), then rendering it in the child's template using [NgTemplateOutlet](https://angular.io/api/common/NgTemplateOutlet) if it's presented, otherwise, rendering another default template.

You can do something like the following:

**Child's component class:**

```js
@ContentChild('appChecklistTitle') appChecklistTitle: TemplateRef<any>; // You can use the preferred type instead of `any` here.
```

**Child's component template:**

```html
<ng-container
  *ngIf="appChecklistTitle; else default"
  [ngTemplateOutlet]="appChecklistTitle"
></ng-container>
<ng-template #default>YOUR DEFAULT TEMPLATE HERE</ng-template>
```

**Parent's component template:**

```html
<app-child>
  <ng-template #appChecklistTitle>CUSTOME TEMPLATE HERE</ng-template>
</app-child>
```